# Sidekiq job error handling and retries inside parent job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, sidekiq

I have a Job which spawns other jobs and do few things inline.

abc_job.rb

```
class AbcJob
  def perform
    post_events
  end

  private

  def post_events
    foo
    bar
    done
  end

  def foo
    OneJob.perform_later({})
  end

  def bar
    TwoJob.perform_later({})
  end

  def done
    ThreeJob.perform_later({})
  end
end
```

Need to handle errors and add retries to all the jobs inside `abc_job`.

One way would be to add begin rescue inside `post_events` for all the methods.

Please suggest best way to do it and also need to add retries to child jobs.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is to use metaprogramming. You can create a external module say `ExceptionHandler` -> you can `rescue` your errors here with what to do when a error is handled -> then include this module in your `AbcJob` file.

Ex:

1. Create a module file:

   ```rb
   module ExceptionHandler
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

     # Define custom error subclasses - rescue catches `StandardErrors`
     class InvalidToken < StandardError; end
     class MissingToken < StandardError; end

     included do
       # Define in-built handlers
       rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :four_not_four
       rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :four_not_four

       # Define custom handlers
       rescue_from ExceptionHandler::MissingToken, with: :unauthorized_request
       rescue_from ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken, with: :unauthorized_request
     end

     private
       ## Action on what to do when error occurs
       def four_not_four
         redirect_to root_path, alert: "This page was not found"
       end

       def unauthorized_request
         redirect_to root_path, alert: "You're not authorized to perform this request"
       end
   end
   ```
2. Then in your `Abcjob` file, just include this module:

   ```rb
   class AbcJob
     include ExceptionHandler

     def perform
       post_events
     end

     ...
   end
   ```
3. Now, whenever a job throws an handler, this will trigger the methods that you mentioned in `ExceptionHandler` and run them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no an easy way to achieve the goal of handling the errors from a child-job inside the parent using Sidekiq. They key of the problem is that the `AbcJob` just makes a schedule for the children and then it is done. The children jobs can be technically executed even on another server and all the exceptions are happening there. Usually, in the time when the children are processing, the parent job is already finished, so there is no context (process) where an exception can be handled. With Sidekiq the only way to handle an exception inside the child job and perform some compensation actions from there. The error handling may include a restart or another logic (including the execution of a parent job directly).
Probably a simplest solution - don't run children jobs asynchronously, just execute them within the same parent job. This is may be not exactly what was requested but could work as an option.

On the side note - you may probably have a look on Elixir/Erlang where the desired behaviour is included into language design:

Elixir(Erlang) has a nice tooling to spawn sub-processes and monitor their statuses: parent process can easily await for all children to finish and handle their results, including exceptions. http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2018/04/elixir-processes-and-this-thing-called-otp/